# Como limpar uma lista sem perder todas posições?

Tags: c#, .net, array, lista

Em minha aplicação em **C#**, tenho uma lista `List< float>` onde armazeno dados que chegam pela *porta Serial*. Com a execução da aplicação em andamento essa lista começa a ficar enorme. Não estou conseguindo limpar a mesma por se tratar de um monitoramento em tempo real onde eu traço gráficos com os valores dessa lista e nesses gráficos são utilizadas as 2000 ultimas posições dessa lista. A minha pergunta é: Como eu posso limpar essa lista sem perder os valores das 2000 ultimas posições? Ou talvez, como tornar essa lista temporária, onde quando eu alcançar **N** posições é criado outra lista e armazenadas as 2000 últimas posições da lista anterior?

Comment: Podes usar linq

Comment: Certamente a solução correta é outra, mas sem saber detalhes nem temos como ajudar. Limpar não faz muito sentido, inclusive pelo que está dizendo pode ter problemas de concorrência. Talvez você queira usar uma fila e não uma lista.

Comment: Se fornecer mais informação conseguiremos dar uma resposta mais objectiva

Comment: Cara, eu tentei explicar ao máximo, o código é muito grande pra colar aqui, porém a idéia do Maniero parece funcionar, não tinha pensado em usar uma fila

Comment: Como eu disse, esse é um problema XY, você quer a solução para o problema errado.

Comment: Você está buscando eficiência, e as soluções apresentadas não são ineficientes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lista = lista.Skip(lista.Count - 2000).ToList();
```

Comment: realmente não tinha pensado nessa solução

Comment: valeu amigo, funcionou muito bem]

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer desta forma, o código esta comentado, explicando o seu funcionamento

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static List<float> lista = new List<float>(2000);

    public static void addItemLista(float valor){
        //Se a lista ainda não completou os 2000 registro simplesmente adiciona mais um registro
        if(lista.Count < 2000){
            lista.Add(valor);
        }else{//Se tem mais de 2000 registro, ele remove o primeiro e adiciona o novo item
            lista.Remove(lista.FirstOrDefault());
            lista.Add(valor);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {   
        //Teste adicionando 2020 registro
        for (int i = 0; i < 2020; i++)
        {
            addItemLista(i);
        }

        //Resultado
        lista.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));
    }
}
```

[Executar](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TRWfWs)

Answer (score 2):

Vamos imaginar a seguinte lista

```
List<float> lista = new List<float>();
```

Para apagar toda a lista voce faria

```
 lista.Clear();
```

Entao para apagar manter as ultimas 2000 o que eu faria seria criar uma lista com base nesse requisito

```
var novaLista = (from p in lista 
                        orderby p descending
                        select p).Take(2000);
```

ou então

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lista.Count -2001; i++)
{
   lista.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

usando Queue

```
Queue Q = new Queue();

while(Q.Count > 2000)
{
  Q.Dequeue()
}
```